# Cannot find CSS files in Bower Components when using Grunt

Tags: css, backbone.js, sass, gruntjs, bower

I'm trying to import a CSS stylesheet into a .sass file from a component. In this example, the component is bootstrap-select and the import looks like this:

```
@import 'bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.css'
```

This builds successfully but the browser is unable to find the file, I receive the following error in the browser:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/styles/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.css 404 (Not Found)
```

Is there anything special I need to setup to have .css files included in builds?

Answer (score 1):

In order to import the code of the file into your Sass file the imported file needs to have a `.sass` or `.scss` ending. If the file ends with `.css` the code will not be sucked in and it just is a normal CSS `@import` statement that creates an HTTP request.

Just copy the css file you want to import, change the file ending to `.scss` and `@import` that file. Sass will then suck in the code and replace the `@import` statement with it in your CSS file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have already performed this as a temporary workaround but it defeats the purpose of using bower components. Ideally, you want to install or update a bower component without any manual handling.

Comment: That's true, but the fact that you can't import CSS code into Sass via @import just means you need a Sass version of bootstrap-select that is available through Bower. If there is no Sass version available then you can't manage that library through Bower.

Answer (score 0):

What Kahlil said; but I would propose using [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) instead as it gives you a lot more flexibility when it comes to what you can/can't include. I'm using this in production and it's very good; you can completely tailor your build, including variables so that you can tweak the button colours, spacing and such. For example:

```
/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Only include the parts of Bootstrap that we are actually using.
|---------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

$navbar-margin-bottom: 0;

@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass/lib/variables";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass/lib/mixins";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass/lib/normalize";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass/lib/print";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass/lib/scaffolding";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass/lib/type";

// etc
```

Add it to your `bower.json` (`bootstrap-sass`) and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your suggestion, I'm already using sass-bootstrap but for other bower components that are not sass ready (i.e. bootstrap-select), the solution appears to be a manual adjustment.

Comment: Sorry, I thought select was part of twbs, my bad. RE: manual adjustment; looks like it, yes. If you're making an adjustment to the source code that you think would be beneficial to others, then submit a pull request to the original repository. That would then benefit others who were looking for a SASS version of the component, and also if it were to be updated all future versions would be SASS ready right from within the Bower package. The alternative is to probably use something like `grunt-contrib-copy` and rename the extension to CSS, placing the file in a different directory. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a ruby gem which allows for the functionality described called [sass-css-importer](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-css-importer), which allows for the following syntax to be used to include files ending with `.css` from within `.scss` files:

```
@import "CSS:../../bower_components/alertify/themes/alertify.core";
@import "CSS:../../bower_components/alertify/themes/alertify.default";
@import "CSS:../../bower_components/normalize-css/normalize";
@import "../../../bower_components/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/_bourbon";
@import "../../../bower_components/neat/app/assets/stylesheets/_neat";
```

It can be added to a `Gemfile` like so:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "sass-css-importer"
```

And required in the `Gruntfile`:

```
sass:
  options:
    quiet: true
    require: 'sass-css-importer'
  static:
    files: [
      expand: true
      cwd: 'source/styles'
      src: ['*.scss']
      dest: 'build/styles'
      ext:
```

YMMV. Good luck!